# Restrict the draggable mesh inside the shapeGeometry

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I want to restrict the draggable rugGeometry inside the L Shape.
How to fix this issue. Please help me out, I am beginner in Three.js

I have attached the code below where I have create L Shape using shapeGeometry and rug shape using planeGeometry but it is not draggable on the right side of L Shape.

Also the rug should not move outside the L Shape boundaries.

```
// L Shape Geometry Code
    var points = [
      // all of them are on the xz-plane
      new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, 5),
      new THREE.Vector3(65, 0, 5),
      new THREE.Vector3(65, 0, 35),
      new THREE.Vector3(35, 0, 35),
      new THREE.Vector3(35, 0, 65),
      new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, 65),
      new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, 5),
    ];

    // Create an array of Vector2 points by extracting x and z coordinates
    var vertices = points.map(function (point) {
      return new THREE.Vector2(point.x, point.z);
    });

    var geom = new THREE.Shape(vertices);

    lGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(geom);

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(lGeometry, material);

    //Main part for orbit controls
    mesh.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

    scene.add(mesh);


//Create Rug Geometry
createRugFn = () => {
      console.log("inside createRugFn");
      var rugTextureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(rugTexture);

      rugGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(18, 25);
      const rugMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: rugTextureLoader,
        depthTest: false,
        needsUpdate: true,
      });

      rugMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rugGeometry, rugMaterial);
      rugMesh.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

   
      rugMesh.position.set(15, 0, -35);


      scene.add(rugMesh);
      addResizeDrag(rugMesh);
    };

// ================ RUG CODE (Resizable and draggable planeGeometry) ================

    function addResizeDrag(rugMesh) {
      let isDragging = false;
      let previousMousePosition = { x: 0, y: 0 };
      let planeOffset = new THREE.Vector3();

      function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
        isDragging = true;

        previousMousePosition = {
          x: event.clientX,
          y: event.clientY,
        };

        const intersects = getIntersects(event.layerX, event.layerY);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {
          planeOffset.copy(intersects[0].point).sub(rugMesh.position);
        }
      }

      function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
        if (isDragging) {
          const deltaMove = {
            x: event.clientX - previousMousePosition.x,
            y: event.clientY - previousMousePosition.y,
          };

          if (planeOffset.length() > 0) {
            // const intersects = getIntersects(event.layerX, event.layerY);
            // if (intersects.length > 0) {

            //   rugMesh.position.copy(intersects[0].point.sub(planeOffset));
            // }

            const intersects = getIntersects(event.layerX, event.layerY);
            if (intersects.length > 0) {
              const newPosition = intersects[0].point.sub(planeOffset);

              // Get the dimensions of the lGeometry
              const planeWidth = boundingBox.max.x - boundingBox.min.x;
              const planeHeight = boundingBox.max.y - boundingBox.min.y;

              // Get the dimensions of the rugGeometry
              const rugWidth = rugMesh.geometry.parameters.width;
              const rugHeight = rugMesh.geometry.parameters.height;
              // console.log(mesh);

              // Calculate the boundaries of the planeGeometry
              const xMin = -(planeWidth / 2) + rugWidth / 2;
              const xMax = planeWidth / 2 - rugWidth / 2;
              const zMin = -(planeHeight / 2) + rugHeight / 2;
              const zMax = planeHeight / 2 - rugHeight / 2;

              // Clamp the newPosition within the planeGeometry boundaries
              const clampedX = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(newPosition.x, xMin, xMax);
              const clampedZ = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(newPosition.z, zMin, zMax);
              newPosition.set(clampedX, newPosition.y, clampedZ);
              rugMesh.position.copy(newPosition);
            }
          }

          previousMousePosition = {
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY,
          };
        }
      }

      function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
        if (isDragging) {
          var boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);

          const deltaMove = {
            x: event.clientX - previousMousePosition.x,
            y: event.clientY - previousMousePosition.y,
          };

          if (planeOffset.length() > 0) {
            const intersects = getIntersects(event.layerX, event.layerY);
            if (intersects.length > 0) {
              const newPosition = intersects[0].point.sub(planeOffset);

              // Get the dimensions of the lGeometry
              const planeWidth = boundingBox.max.x - boundingBox.min.x;
              const planeDepth = boundingBox.max.z - boundingBox.min.z;

              // Get the dimensions of the rugGeometry
              const rugWidth = rugMesh.geometry.parameters.width;
              const rugDepth = rugMesh.geometry.parameters.height;

              // // Calculate the boundaries of the lGeometry
              // const xMin = boundingBox.min.x + rugWidth / 2;
              // const xMax = boundingBox.max.x/1.855 - rugWidth / 2;
              // const zMin = boundingBox.min.z/1.855 + rugDepth / 2;
              // const zMax = boundingBox.max.z - rugDepth / 2;

              // Calculate the boundaries of the lGeometry
              const xMin = boundingBox.min.x + rugWidth / 2;
              const xMax = boundingBox.max.x / 1.855 - rugWidth / 2;
              const zMin = boundingBox.min.z + rugDepth / 2;
              const zMax = boundingBox.max.z - rugDepth / 2;

              // Clamp the newPosition within the lGeometry boundaries
              const clampedX = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(newPosition.x, xMin, xMax);
              const clampedZ = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(newPosition.z, zMin, zMax);
              newPosition.set(clampedX, newPosition.y, clampedZ);
              rugMesh.position.copy(newPosition);
            }
          }

          previousMousePosition = {
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY,
          };
        }
      }

      function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
        isDragging = false;
        planeOffset.set(0, 0, 0);
      }

      function getIntersects(x, y) {
        const mouseVector = new THREE.Vector3(
          (x / window.innerWidth) * 0.9 * 2 - 1,
          -(y / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
          0.5
        );
        // console.log("mouseVector:", mouseVector);
        const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouseVector, camera);
        // console.log("ray:", raycaster.intersectObject(rugMesh));
        return raycaster.intersectObject(rugMesh);
      }

      function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = ((window.innerWidth * 0.8) / window.innerHeight) * 0.8;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth * 0.8, window.innerHeight * 0.8);
      }

      window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", onDocumentMouseDown);
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", onDocumentMouseMove);
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", onDocumentMouseUp);
    }

    // ================ RUG CODE (Resizable and draggable planeGeometry) ================
```